# Private NuGet feed and docker cache (windows)

Tags: .net, windows, docker, nuget

I am currently experimenting with using Docker for our build process to make it easy to reproduce build results from any developer machine/server.

The complication is that I have several private packages my software depends on, which requires me to a variable to the build script before restoring packages. This in turn causes docker to not use the cached output of the nuget restore step.

Environment is Windows Containers, .Net Framework 4.8 code.

My (simplified) Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS dotnetbuild
RUN Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.ps1 -OutFile installcredprovider.ps1; `
    .\installcredprovider.ps1 -AddNetfx; `
    del installcredprovider.ps1

WORKDIR C:/app

COPY ./*.sln .
COPY ./MyProject/*.csproj /MyProject/packages.config ./MyProject/
COPY ./nuget.config .

ARG PAT
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{`"endpointCredentials`": [{`"endpoint`":`"myfeed1.json`", `"username`":`"docker`", `"password`":`"${PAT}`"}, {`"endpoint`":`"myfeed2.json`", `"username`":`"docker`", `"password`":`"${PAT}`"}]}"

RUN nuget restore

COPY . .
RUN msbuild
```

Ideally I would like to prevent nuget restore downloading ALL packages every time the project builds.

My initial idea was to first restore the public nuget packages (which is the majority), and then restore the private packages on every build as a trade-off:

```
RUN nuget restore 
COPY ./nuget.config .

ARG PAT
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{`"endpointCredentials`": [{`"endpoint`":`"myfeed1.json`", `"username`":`"docker`", `"password`":`"${PAT}`"}, {`"endpoint`":`"myfeed2.json`", `"username`":`"docker`", `"password`":`"${PAT}`"}]}"
RUN nuget restore
```

However, the first nuget command can't find all the packages, and gives an error, failing the docker build:

```
    Unable to find version '1.0.0.0' of package 'MyPrivatePackage'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'MyPrivatePackage.1.0.0.0' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
```

I could restore packages on the host machine, and send the packages folder to the docker context, but I'm trying to avoid installing anything besides Docker on the host machine.

Currently I have implemented a batch file with the following contents, and call that in place of the first nuget restore command:

```
nuget.exe restore
exit 0
```

Which works, but I feel is a rather dirty solution.

I'm looking for any ideas that will allow the nuget restore step to be cached without failing the docker build, or installing the .net sdk on the host machine.

Comment: >> "Ideally I would like to prevent nuget restore downloading ALL packages every time the project builds."

In what scenario does this happen?  Assuming you haven't changed your solution, project, or nuget.config file, Docker should cache the layers up to but not including the `COPY . .` line.  So if you were to just make code changes in your project and rerun a Docker build, it shouldn't attempt to restore layers again.  If any of the files I mentioned _had_ changed, then restoring the packages is the right thing to do.

Comment: Why are you using a custom build script instead of `dotnet nuget add source` with user name and token?

Comment: @MattThalman I have to set the access token to access the private nuget feed in Azure Devops, this changes every run (on the build server, not on my local machine), so everything after ENV VSS_NUGET* is invalidated every run.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The package source urls are already in my nuget.config file. I could use `dotnet nuget add source`, but I am not sure how I could use it without either storing the password in an unsafe location, or running into the same issue with the password changing every time I run the script?

I took this approach for authentication based on samples from Microsoft: 
https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/samples/dockerfile.sample.txt

Comment: Presumably, your build server's state is maintained across builds such that it could even take advantage of Docker's caching?  There's no calls to `docker system prune`, for example?

Comment: @MattThalman yes, caching in itself works fine, outside the scope of this issue there is also an angular build for the client-side app in the same dockerfile, that is skipped perfectly fine. 

The cache is just invalidated by the changing Environment variable. Perhaps I should note that the value of PAT is `$(System.AccessToken)` in my Azure Devops Pipeline.

The invalidation behavior is by design for docker: 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#impact-on-build-caching

Comment: Instead of using a batch file, a simpler method of ignoring the error from the restore is something like this: `RUN nuget restore || ver>nul`.  That will ensure the exit code is 0 even if the restore fails.  Kind of ugly but it avoids the need for a batch file.

Comment: @MattThalman That's really simple, and an excellent compromise. No changes to the host, and no extra files cluttering my build system. It did not work out of the box because I'm using powershell as scripting host, but it was easy enough to adapt: `RUN nuget restore; cmd /c "ver>nul";`. If you make it an answer I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing two passes of `nuget restore` seems like the best available approach to me. As you mentioned the first execution will return a non-zero exit code because of the restore failure for the private feed which will cause the Docker build to fail. There are techniques amongst the various shells for compensating for a non-zero exit code when you want the exit code to be zero. This allows Docker build to proceed even if the `nuget restore` command resulted in an error.

These are examples of how this can be done in various shells:

#### Windows CMD shell

```
RUN nuget restore || ver>nul
```

#### PowerShell

```
RUN nuget restore; exit 0
```

#### Bash

```
RUN dotnet restore || true
```

Comment: Note that `RUN nuget restore; exit 0` did not work for me when I tried this, but `RUN nuget restore; cmd /c "ver>nul";` does. Presumably when running in powershell, it takes the last run program exit code rather than the code of the powershell shell itself.